# Blazor components - namespace move

Tags: visual-studio, blazor

I am experiencing problem in VS 2022 in Blazor complex project. After moving Blazor components to different namespace/folder the components are not functional any more. My component does not 'recognize' other Blazor components anymore. For example custom component MudTable from MudBlazor namespace:

[image: MudTable not known]

I would like to be able move Blazor components easily as simple classes.

Sometimes it helps to specify the same namespace in razor file to match namespace in partial code behind class, but sometimes I end up creating component (razor and cs files) with different name (copying the same code). This is very time consuming. I am not able to reproduce the described bug in Simple Projects. I have tried to reproduce the issue but it works fine (with minor VS bug) as described below. I will keep trying to reproduce the issue on Sample project.

Please find below scenarios working fine:

***Simple scenario working fine***

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Create Blazor Server App
2. Create folders

   - `Components`
   - `Components\Sub1`
   - `Components\Sub2`
3. Add new Razor component e.g. `MyComponent1.razor` to folder `Components\Sub1`
4. Verify that `<MyComponent1\>` works on some page. Eg. add lines to Index.razor:

   ```
   @using BlazorApp1.Components.Sub1
   <MyComponent1 />
   ```
5. Move `MyComponent1.razor` to folder `Components\Sub2`
6. Update Index.razor:

   ```
   @using BlazorApp1.Components.Sub2
   <MyComponent1 />
   ```
7. It works fine

**More complex scenario with minor bug**

1. Create Blazor Server App
2. Create folders

   - `Components`
   - `Components\Sub1`
   - `Components\Sub2`
3. Add new Razor component e.g. `MyComponent1.razor` to folder `Components\Sub1`
4. Add behind the class to 'MyComponent1.razor.cs' to folder `Components\Sub1`:

   ```
      using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

      namespace BlazorApp1.Components.Sub1
      {
       public partial class MyComponent1:ComponentBase
       {

       }
      }
   ```
5. Verify that `<MyComponent1\>` works on some page. Eg. add lines to Index.razor:

   ```
   @using BlazorApp1.Components.Sub1
   <MyComponent1 />
   ```
6. Rename folder `Components\Sub1` to `Components\Sub1Renamed`.
7. Visual studio does not display any error and project can be compiled/started. Code behind is even displayed 'linked' to razor file:

   [image: Behind the code]

This seems as a VS bug to me.

1. When project is started Component1 is invisible on Index page, because component 'BlazorApp1.Components.Sub1.Component1`has no visual code defined, because it has only non-visual definition 'behind the code'. The file 'Component1.razor' with visual is not used at all because it is in unused namespace`BlazorApp1.Components.Sub1Renamed`
2. Update Index.razor:

```
@using BlazorApp1.Components.Sub1Renamed
<MyComponent1 />
```

1. When project is started, Component1 is visible on Index page (but I assume that no code behind is processed)

   [image: Visible Component1]

Do you have any hint, how to make it work for blazor components ?

Comment: I right click change namespace to match folder structure. Unless your using and `@namespace` directive in your component. This will be the namespace used by the compiler for the .razor mark up part, they must align.

Comment: You are right. In simple projects can be used 'Sync Namespaces' and it works fine. I have tried to reproduce my issue on sample project, but I am not able to find the steps to reproduce the issue. I have updated my Question to be more clear.

Comment: VS 2022 seems to sometimes have problems with Razor components when you move or rename them.  I now always move/rename files outside the project in File Explorer and I always fully namespace all my Razor files.

Comment: @MrC aka Shaun Curtis Thank you for your hint with "File explorer". I will try it. I was trying to figure out "How to reproduce the bug", to report it to Microsoft, but it seems it works OK in small projects or the bug is random.

Comment: I had the same problem. I think unloading/reloading project did the trick for me.

Comment: Restart VS and do a rebuild.  If the problem persists then you have a genuine syntax errror somewhere, find and fix it.